# Sentinel3 OLCI (chl) Average of netcdf files on Python

Tags: python, netcdf, satellite-image

I'm having some troubles with trying to get a monthly average with Sentinel 3 images on... Everything, really. Python, Matlab, we are two people getting stuck in this problem.

The main reason deals with the fact that these images' information is not on a single netcdf file, neatly put with coordinates and products. Instead, they are all in separate files inside a one day folder as
[different .nc files with different information each, about one single satellite image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z7yy.png). SNAP uses an xmlxs file to work with all of these separate .nc files as I understand it.

Now, I though it would be a good idea to try to merge and create/edit the .nc files as to create a new daily .nc which included the chlorophyll, the coordinates and, might as well add it, time. Later on, I would merge these new ones so to be able to make a monthly mean with xarray. At least that was my idea but I can't do the first part. It might be an obvious solution however here's what I tried, using the xarray module

```
import os
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
  
nc_folder = df_try.iloc[0] #folder where the image files are

#open dataset in xarray
nc_chl = xr.open_dataset(str(nc_folder['path']) + '/' + 'chl_nn.nc') #path to chlorophyll file 
nc_chl

n_coord =xr.open_dataset(str(nc_folder['path'])+ '/'+ 'geo_coordinates.nc') #path to coordinates file

n_time = xr.open_dataset(str(nc_folder['path'])+ '/' + 'time_coordinates.nc') #path to time file

ds_grid = [[nc_chl], [n_coord], [n_time]]

combined = xr.combine_nested(ds_grid, concat_dim=[None, None]) 
combined #dataset with all but not recognizing coordinates

ds = combined.rename({'latitude': 'lat', 'longitude': 'lon', 'time_stamp' : 'time'}).set_coords(['lon', 'lat', 'time']) #dataset recognizing coordinates as coordinates
ds
```

which gives a dataset with

Dimensions: columns 4865  rows: 4091

3 coordinates (lat, lon and time) and the chl variable.

Now, it doesn't save to netcdf4 (I tried but there was an error) but I was also thinking if anyone knew of another way to make an average? I have images from three years (beginning on 2017 to ending on 2019) I would need to average in different ways (monthly, seasonally...). My main current problem is that the chlorophyll values are separate from the geographical coordinates so directly only using the chlorophyll files should not work and would just make a mess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The better solution would be to add coordinates to the chlorophyll files. Though without further info I canot suggest how

Comment: well, I've been tinkering with xarray with combine_nested (as per the code), trying to combine both the chlorophyll and the coordinates into a single .nc file, saving using dataset.to_netcdf. I managed to save it, however it gives this warning?
«SerializationWarning: saving variable lat with floating point data as an integer dtype without any _FillValue to use for NaNs» The file does seem to work for the daily images

Comment: cdo might be easier: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/FAQ#How-can-I-add-coordinate-variables-latitude-and-longitude-if-missing-in-the-data-file

Answer (score 5):

Two options here:

### Using xarray

In xarray you can add them as **coordinates**. It is a bit tricky as the coordinates in the `geo_coordinates.nc` file are multidimensional as well.

A possible solution is the following:

```
import netCDF4 
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# paths
root = r'C:<your_path>\S3B_OL_2_WFR____20201015.SEN3\chl_nn.nc'        #set path to chl file
coor = r'C:<your_path>\S3B_OL_2_WFR____20201015.SEN3\geo_coordinates.nc' #set path to the coordinates file

# loading xarray datasets
ds = xr.open_dataset(root)
olci_geo_coords = xr.open_dataset(coor)

# extracting coordinates
lat = olci_geo_coords.latitude.data
lon = olci_geo_coords.longitude.data

# assign coordinates to the chl dataset (needs to refer to both the dimensions of our dataset)
ds = ds.assign_coords({"lon":(["rows","columns"], lon), "lat":(["rows","columns"], lat)})

# clip the image (add your own coordinates)
area_of_interest = ds.where((10 < ds.lon) & (ds.lon < 12) & (58 < ds.lat) & (ds.lat < 59), drop=True)

# simple plot with coordinates as axis
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
area_of_interest["CHL_NN"].plot(x="lon",y="lat")
```

Even simpler is to add them as **variables** in a new dataset:

```
# path to the folder
root = r'C:<your_path>\S3B_OL_2_WFR____20201015.SEN3\*.nc'        #set path to chl file

# create a dataset by combining nc files (coordinates will become variables)
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(root,combine = 'by_coords')
```

But in this case when you plot the image or clip it you cannot use the coordinates directly.

### Using snappy

In python the snappy package is available and based on SNAP toolbox (which is implemented on JAVA). Check: https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SNAP/pages/19300362/How+to+use+the+SNAP+API+from+Python

Once installed (unfortunately snappy supports only python 2.7, 3.3 or 3.4), you can use the available SNAP function directly on python to aggregate your satellite images and create week/month averages. You then do not need to merge the lon, lat netcdf file as you will work on the `xfdumanifest.xml` and SNAP will take care of that.

This is an example. It performs aggregation as well (mean calculated on two chl nc files):

```
from snappy import ProductIO, WKTReader
from snappy import jpy
from snappy import GPF
from snappy import HashMap

# setting the aggregator method
aggregator_average_config = snappy.jpy.get_type('org.esa.snap.binning.aggregators.AggregatorAverage$Config')
agg_avg_chl = aggregator_average_config('CHL_NN')

# creating the hashmap to store the parameters
HashMap = snappy.jpy.get_type('java.util.HashMap')
parameters = HashMap()

#creating the aggregator array
aggregators = snappy.jpy.array('org.esa.snap.binning.aggregators.AggregatorAverage$Config', 1)
#adding my aggregators in the list
aggregators[0] = agg_avg_chl

# set parameters
# output directory 
dir_out = 'level-3_py_dynamic.dim'
parameters.put('outputFile', dir_out)

# number of rows (directly linked with resolution)
parameters.put('numRows', 66792) # to have about 300 meters spatial resolution

# aggregators list
parameters.put('aggregators', aggregators)

# Region to clip the aggregation on
wkt="POLYGON ((8.923302175377243 59.55648108694149, 13.488748662344074 59.11388968719029,12.480488185001589 56.690625338725155, 8.212366327767503 57.12425256476263,8.923302175377243 59.55648108694149))"
geom = WKTReader().read(wkt)
parameters.put('region', geom)

# Source product path 
path_15 = r"C:<your_path>\S3B_OL_2_WFR____20201015.SEN3\xfdumanifest.xml"
path_16 = r"C:\<your_path>\S3B_OL_2_WFR____20201016.SEN3\xfdumanifest.xml"
path = path_15 + "," + path_16
parameters.put('sourceProductPaths', path)

#result = snappy.GPF.createProduct('Binning', parameters, (source_p1, source_p2))

# create results
result = snappy.GPF.createProduct('Binning', parameters) #to be used with product paths specified in the parameters hashmap

print("results stored in: {0}".format(dir_out) )
```

I am quite new and interested in the topic and would be happy to hear your/other solutions!